# Create flutter image carousel

Tags: image, flutter, plugins, dart, carousel

How can i create a Carousel of Images like the example below?

[Image Carousel Overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q03RB.png)
I try it with the following code but that only set the images next to each other.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  width: 150,
  child: CarouselSlider(items: ['https://picsum.photos/200/300','https://picsum.photos/200/300','https://picsum.photos/200/300'].map((i) {
    return Builder(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        width: 150, 
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amber),
      child: GestureDetector(child: Image.network(i,fit:BoxFit.fill,),
      onTap: (){
       //add TODO:
      },
      )
    );
    },
  );
  }).toList(),
  height: 200.0,

  ),
);
```

I has try it with alignment, but that did not go well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_multi_carousel

code snippet

```
Center(
        child: Carousel(
            height: 350.0,
            width: 350,
            type: "slideswiper",
            indicatorType: "bar",
            arrowColor: Colors.white,
            axis: Axis.horizontal,
            showArrow: true,
            children: List.generate(
                7,
                (i) => Center(
                      child: Container(color: Colors.red),
                    ))),
      ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_multi_carousel/carousel.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Carousel Demo',
      home: CarouselExample(),
    );
  }
}

class CarouselExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Carousel(
            height: 350.0,
            width: 350,
            type: "slideswiper",
            indicatorType: "bar",
            arrowColor: Colors.white,
            axis: Axis.horizontal,
            showArrow: true,
            children: List.generate(
                7,
                (i) => Center(
                      child: Container(color: Colors.red),
                    ))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hey thanks that work. On last question. How can i see more than a small part of the images in the background. Optimal i want wo see half of the images in the background

Comment: In carousel.dart source code , first line of Widget build,  offset = widget.type == "slideswiper" ? 0.8 : 1.0;  offset is a fixed value, you can change 0.8 to 0.5 directly. and hot reload won't work, you need to restart your application.